# How to use post method in submitting forms of specified data to send to server in html using jquery or js

Tags: jquery, post, get, forms, http-post

I am trying to use post method to post the specified data to the server and get some data message in return. How can i send the specified data using post method.

```
AUTHENTICATION:  
POST: URL
Inputs:  
type = csv | json 
roll = alphanumeric string 
dob = mmddyyyy 
method = auth 
devId = <developer id> 
Output:   
result = success | failure 
nKey = an encrypted key for the particular user 
message = <failure reason>
```

This is the Form Code

```
 <form id="login">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="date" placeholder="date of Birth" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{7}" title="X9999999" placeholder="XX999" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button" />                                           

                    </li>
                </ul>
```

How can i send the form data with the input data using post method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
$.post( "URL", $('#login').serialize(), 
    function( data ) { alert(data); }
);
```

The page specified in URL must return the message, you will get on 'data' all your URL page print out.

Comment: can you please explain with the above question in brief

Comment: Shure, at least i can try. The URL should be a page, probably a php. If that is the case, in that page you will receive your input data in the post variable like $_POST["date"], etc. You then can process that info in any way you like and echo your processed answer, you will get that echo answer back in de original page in de 'data' variable.

Comment: do you have any specific question? did you mean the php code?

Comment: how do i post request of html form to php server on button click of "login"

Comment: Using the jQuery code i give you in the answer. You can trigger that code with $('#login').submit(function() { }); or you can use it after a validation or any thing you like.

Comment: how do i post the devd id along with the other fields to php server